# How to use the Dojo Store for Clientside Data Caching?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am having difficulty understanding how to implement **client side caching**. In my sample code, each call using `store.get(id)` creates a new HTTP request. As far as I can tell, data is not retrieved from local memory.

In the documentation for [dojo/store/Cache](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/Cache.html), it clearly states that data is stored in local memory cache after the first GET request is completed. Subsequent requests are pulled from local memory.

However, using Firefox Web Inspector I see my code creates a **new HTTP request** each time. What am I doing wrong?

### Code:

```
require(["dojo/store/JsonRest", "dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/store/Cache", "dojo/domReady!"], function(JsonRest, Memory, Cache) {

    var restStore = new JsonRest({target:"/rest/Vendor/"});
    var memoryStore = new Memory({});
    var store = new Cache(restStore, memoryStore);

    var object = store.get("5").then(function(value) {
        console.log("Vendor Name: ", value.name);
    });

    var object = store.get("5").then(function(value) {
        console.log("Vendor Name: ", value.name);
    });

    var object = store.get("5").then(function(value) {
        console.log("Vendor Name: ", value.name);
    });

});
```

### Web Inspector Output

```
[22:28:59.585] GET http://my-website-url.com/rest/Vendor/5 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 596ms]
[22:28:59.588] GET http://my-website-url/rest/Vendor/5 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 40ms]
[22:28:59.153] "Vendor Name: " "Company E"
[22:28:59.589] GET http://my-website-url/rest/Vendor/5 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 36ms]
[22:28:59.196] "Vendor Name: " "Company E"
[22:28:59.235] "Vendor Name: " "Company E"
```

### JSON Output from Rest Call

```
[
    {"name":"Company A","vendorId":1,"active":1},
    {"name":"Company B","vendorId":2,"active":1},
    {"name":"Company C","vendorId":3,"active":1},
    {"name":"Company D","vendorId":4,"active":1},
    {"name":"Company E","vendorId":5,"active":1}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to supply an "idProperty" to both the [JsonRest store](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/store/JsonRest.html) and the Memory store, because the "Cache" will try to lookup an object with identifier "5" in it's cache. Since you haven't specified which property identifies an object, it will not find an entry in the cache and do the HTTP request again.

In short: i would expect it to work when you specify the idProperty to the store, like this:

```
var restStore = new JsonRest({target:"/rest/Vendor/", idProperty: "vendorId"});
var memoryStore = new Memory({idProperty: "vendorId"});
```